# Images are not showing at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

In my master page, I have used 6 image buttons, but only two are showing - home and logout button (1st and last). 
There are no issues at Design or Compile Time.

The site is working properly on my local system but when I am deploying it to the client system, above issue happens.

I have tried to debug on the client system using VS2019 but there too the same issues occur.

Here is the my design:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnHome" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Home.png" 
    Width="59" Height="47" ToolTip="Home" CausesValidation="False" 
    OnClick="btnHome_Click" onmouseout="this.src='Images/Home.png';"
    onmouseover="this.src='Images/Home_roll.png';"  BorderWidth="0"/>

<asp:ImageButton ID="btnMaster" runat="server"  ImageUrl="~/Images/Master.png" 
    Width="59" Height="47"
    ToolTip="Master" CausesValidation="False" OnClick="btnMaster_Click" 
     onmouseout="this.src='Images/Master.png';" 
    onmouseover="this.src='Images/Master_roll.png';"   BorderWidth="0" />

<asp:ImageButton ID="btnMailing" runat="server"  ImageUrl="~/Images/mailing.png"
    Width="59" Height="47"
    ToolTip="Mailing"  CausesValidation="False" OnClick="btnMailing_Click" 
    onmouseout="this.src='Images/mailing.png';" 
    onmouseover="this.src='Images/mailing_roll.png'; " />

<asp:ImageButton ID="btnReport" runat="server"  ImageUrl="~/Images/reports.png"
    Width="59" Height="47"
    ToolTip="Report"  CausesValidation="False" OnClick="btnReport_Click" 
    onmouseout="this.src='Images/reports.png';" 
    onmouseover="this.src='Images/reports_roll.png';" />

<asp:ImageButton ID="btnControlPannel" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/settings.png" 
    Width="59" Height="47"
    ToolTip="Control Panel" CausesValidation="False" OnClick="btnControlPannel_Click"
    onmouseout="this.src='Images/settings.png';" 
    onmouseover="this.src='Images/settings_roll.png';"  />

<asp:ImageButton ID="btnLogout" runat="server" Width="59" Height="47" 
    ImageUrl="~/Images/Logout.png" ToolTip="Log Out" CausesValidation="False" 
    OnClick="btnLogout_Click" onmouseout="this.src='Images/Logout.png';" 
    onmouseover="this.src='Images/Logout_Roll.png';" />
```

**EDIT: FYI For all future readers, the site works perfectly fine in the following Systems**

```
Windows Server 2012 R2 - IIS 8.0
Windows 7 Ultimate - IIS 7.5
```

Those 4 images are not being displayed only in the following System:

```
Windows 10 Pro - IIS 10
```

**EDIT2: I don't have the liberty to change the operating system at client side.**

Only thing I can think of, is some issues with IIS configuration; which I am not able to figure not

Comment: Insufficient information. HELP: pls prepend a ~ char in Images/settings.png

Comment: Still, it's giving the same problem.

Comment: Is there any version problem? because I am using the same site which is working on my local system.

Comment: where is the home and logout image in the code. I can see the logout image in the last line in your code. But i cannot find the home image.

Comment: check in the developer tools for the image button. Check if there is any error displayed in the console

Comment: Are you sure you copied all images? Can you access them?